# Python Requests -+ Fiddler

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests

#This URL will behe URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.


endpoint = 'http://212.62.32.199/PracenjeStatusa/en/posiljke.aspx'
authData = '__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJLTcxMTY5NjU2ZGR7njOKaq1g11AmcZw9c9ihygJsEg%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=2E16548E&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBALkmpXkCALNi8izBALAiqiFDgLLss2aAfJVg6RlCVcsmln07F4h1zZ2JNQk&Broj=RS481619407GB&cmdOk=Find'
header = {'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.0', 'X-AspNet-Version': '2.0.50727', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Mon, 21 Jan 2019 21:48:14 GMT', 'Content-Length': '2606'} 



response = requests.post(endpoint, data=authData, headers=header)
print(response.headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

So I'm trying to access tracking status on the local post office website, but after executing the code the headers are returned?